# C Programming, Reading specific sections from file

Tags: c

my question is how can I read specific sections from a file? For instance, if my file was:
`454545454 Joe Brown       70  50  40
656565656 David Smith     80  90 100
383838383 George Williams 95 100  80`

How could I read the first string (9-Digit #), skip over the name, and then read the 3 sets of numbers?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.

Comment: I'm not sure, this is a very difficult problem to solve with only 10 fingers. What have you tried?

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%9s %*s %*s %d %d %d", str_num, &num1, &num2, &num3);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "reading specific sections," read file line by line and save the information you want and discard the others. `scanf` is used to read formatted from an external source into program variables. Since `scanf` returns the number of successful reads from the source, you can use that to do some error checking.

```
char num_string[STR_LEN];
int numbers[3];
char dummy1[STR_LEN], dummy2[STR_LEN];
int num_read = scanf( "%s%s%s%d%d%d", num_string, dummy1, dummy2, &numbers[0], &numbers[1], &numbers[2] );

if( num_read != 6 )
    // error
else
{
    // do stuff with num_string, and numbers[0]-numbers[2]
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain what this code does so the OP can understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could notice that the white space is your sentinel. I'm thinking that maybe you can store the whole file into a char* and asking for this sentinel each time. 
Other solution could be using [atoi](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/&ei=yaMYU6mDC8zv0wHaw4GwBw&usg=AFQjCNESlSVEcL4gW022q5uUVBT3RS3SwA&sig2=5_4CEqnInzXQD_DU5E2TUw&bvm=bv.62577051,d.dmQ) (ascii to int) for validate if it's a number or a letter. You can also read about [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) and [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/).

I think that the best way is to mix both solution... find each sentinel and try to parse it using atoi.

The main idea is that you try to find some pattern in the file that allows you to think the algorithm.
In C, most of the times you have to solve the logic by yourself.

Hope it helps!